# Memory usage of Combine.PerKey on a global window

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

We perform joins over a few PCollections using Combine.PerKey with a custom KeyedCombineFn. PCollections are assigned to a GlobalWindow with a Repeatedly.forever trigger on AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane.

The PCollections contain around 1M keys, but for a given key only a few hundreds elements. The KeyedCombineFn retains around a few KB (sometimes up to 5 MB) of data in its accumulator.

Now that we have increased the amount of data we process in our pipeline we are seeing java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space error. The pipeline runs on n1-highmem-4 machines on Google Cloud Dataflow.

Our assumption is that Dataflow workers manage the state for each key independently, and have heuristics to write/load it to/from disk depending on how much RAM it has available. Hence, the goal is to have individual state fit in one worker's memory.

Is this assumption correct? If so, why could we be seeing OOM errors? If not, do you mind elaborating on how Dataflow workers manage state in memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dataflow workers do behave roughly as you assume, but there is some estimation involved and it's possible something about your data is breaking that.  Do you have a very large discrepancy in the serialized size of your accumulators and the in-memory size of the objects?

The easiest thing to try to fix this would be to run on fewer larger machines such as n1-highmem-8

Comment: Thanks! It is possible that we would be in that case. What do you mean by "large discrepancy"? Is there any rule of thumb to follow to avoid that issue? And by any chance, do you have any pointers on how we could measure that in a running streaming Dataflow jobs?

Comment: The worker harness currently caches 100MB of serialized data's worth of in-memory objects.  If that's enough to exceed the machine limits, you could hit this.  The best thing to do is to analyze a heap dump, which you can get by setting --heapDumpOnOOM: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.java#L226

Comment: Thank you. Changing our serializer seems to have done the trick.